# Prepare Analysis on SoanrQube fails with [SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, status code was: 502

Tags: sonarqube, task

I am using Vnext tfs build to run sonar qube task, but I am getting following error:

```
2019-03-14T06:32:43.4975702Z ##[section]Starting: Prepare analysis on SonarQube
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5045493Z ==============================================================================
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5046300Z Task         : Prepare Analysis Configuration
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5046957Z Description  : Prepare SonarQube analysis configuration
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5047457Z Version      : 4.6.0
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5047947Z Author       : sonarsource
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5048544Z Help         : [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
2019-03-14T06:32:43.5049234Z ==============================================================================
2019-03-14T06:32:47.6077367Z ##**[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, status code was: 502**
2019-03-14T06:32:47.6130134Z ##[section]Finishing: Prepare analysis on SonarQube
```

Our tfs server version is updated to TFS2018 rc2.

Solutions which I had tried: 
Sonar server I am able to browse,
Installed new tfs agent and tried with that.

Need help on this issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same using Azure DevOps with a self hosted buildserver and SonarQube server. Might note that I am using a reverse proxy (IIS with ARR) to use TLS.

Comment: Also stuck on this problem. Thanks

Comment: Anyone have a solution to share?

Answer (score 1):

I had the 404 error: "API GET '/api/server/version' failed, status code was: 404".

To fix this error, I had to use the correct "SonarQube Server Endpoint" which I didn't figure it had changed.

Comment: Referring to the comment, this can ALSO happen in your pipelines when... <cough> <cough> someone updates SonarQube and forgets to do the /setup after the update...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same error with a 503 that was caused by a proxy. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables) using request library environment variables.

> When HTTP_PROXY / http_proxy are set, they will be used to proxy non-SSL requests that do not have an explicit proxy configuration option present. Similarly, HTTPS_PROXY / https_proxy will be respected for SSL requests that do not have an explicit proxy configuration option. It is valid to define a proxy in one of the environment variables, but then override it for a specific request, using the proxy configuration option. Furthermore, the proxy configuration option can be explicitly set to false / null to opt out of proxying altogether for that request.

> Request is also aware of the **NO_PROXY**/**no_proxy** environment variables. These variables provide a granular way to opt out of proxying, on a per-host basis. It should contain a comma separated list of hosts to opt out of proxying. It is also possible to opt of proxying when a particular destination port is used. Finally, the variable may be set to * to opt out of the implicit proxy configuration of the other environment variables.

Add the pipeline variable **NO_PROXY** and **set it equal to the root of the url**/ip for your SonarQube server.